# Allow only positive value in numberfield extjs

Tags: extjs

How can I limit the value in numberfield to be positive only (0 not included) without using a validator.

Comment: There are only workaround solutions to your problem. The best way would be to use the validator. Other not recommended solutions are setting [minValue](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/#!/api/Ext.form.field.Number-cfg-minValue) config to a number a fraction larger than 0 or you could set your own [vtype](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/#!/api/Ext.form.field.Number-cfg-vtype) to disregard the 0 as a valid input, which is just ridiculously more complex than a simple validator.

Answer (score 5):

Use this, it works for me.

```
new Ext.form.NumberField({
    id: 'port',
    fieldLabel: 'Port',
    name: 'port',
    allowNegative: false,
    allowBlank: false,
    minValue: 1,
    anchor: '90%',
    allowDecimals: false
})
```

Comment: You don't need `allowNegative: false`, if you have the `minValue: 1`. And this only works if you really don't want to allow decimals.